# C++ template class static const variable member as map key gives undefined reference

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, undefined-reference

I have a bunch of classes that have a static member that is an enum value. And I have a map somewhere else with this enum as key. Now if I use a template parameter in a function to access the map, I get an undefined reference.

To make it clear, here is a simplified non-working example :

```
template<int T>
struct A
  {
    static const int Type = T;
  }

template<class T>
void fun()
  {
    cout << map_[T::Type] << endl;
  }

map<int, string> map_{{1337, "1337"}};
```

main :

```
fun<A<1337>();
```

gives me (g++ 4.7) :

```
undefined reference to `(anonymous namespace)::A<1337>::Type'
```

However this :

```
template<class T>
void fun()
  {
    auto key = T::Type;
    cout << map_[key] << endl;
  }
```

Compile and prints `1337`

Can someone explain me this behavior?

Comment: @hmjd Well I copied/past your link, compiled, and I get the error. I use g++ 4.7.2-5 on Debian x64. Your link seems to use g++ 4.7.2... I can't really explain

Comment: I think @Lightness has.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `T::Type`, you must *define* it:

```
template<int T>
struct A
{
   static const int Type = T;
}

template <int T>
const int A<T>::Type;
```

Yes, even though you provided its initialiser inline within `A<T>`!

The reason that you may not have been aware of this, is the same reason that you don't get the same problem in your second case — due to the immediate lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, the standard allows the compiler to *optimize* the requirement to refer to `Type` at runtime, able instead to pick out the value at compile-time. The linker then has no need to search for the definition, and you get no error.

---

> `[C++11: 9.4.2/2]:` **The declaration of a static data member in its class definition is not a definition** and may be of an incomplete type other than cv-qualified void. **The definition for a static data member shall appear in a namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition**. In the definition at namespace scope, the name of the static
>   data member shall be qualified by its class name using the :: operator. The initializer expression in the definition of a static data member is in the scope of its class (3.3.7). *[..]*
>
> `[C++11: 9.4.2/3]:` **If a non-volatile `const static` data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer*** in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression
>   is a constant expression (5.19). A `static data` member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the `constexpr` specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every initializer-clause that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression. *[ Note:* In both these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. *—end note ]* **The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.**
>
> `[C++11: 3.2/2]:` *[..]* A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is odr-used unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression (5.19) and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is immediately applied. *[..]*

Answer (score 3):

That is because [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) takes its argument **by reference**, which makes your variable **odr-used** (see paragraph 3.2/3 of the C++11 Standard).

In short, the whole thing boils down to the fact that the compiler needs to know the *address* of an object when it needs to bind a reference to it, and that makes it impossible for it to treat that object just like a pure value and perform inlining.

In that case, you need to provide a *definition* of your static data member at global namespace scope, so that the compiler knows what region of storage that object occupies (i.e. what its address is):

```
template<int T>
const int A::Type;
```

Per paragraph 9.4.2/3 of the C++11 Standard:

> If a non-volatile `const` static data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class
>   definition can specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer* in which every *initializer-clause* that is an *assignment-expression*
>   is a constant expression (5.19). [ ... ] **The member shall still be defined
>   in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not
>   contain an initializer**.

In the first version of your program, on the other hand, you were only using the *value* of your static data member, which means `Type` was not odr-used, and a definition at namespace scope was not needed.